# Is there a way to take user input (comments) using Microsoft flow "Email with Options" feature?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have configured Microsoft flow on a task list item creation using "Send Mail with Options". Different options that I have configured are "Approve" and "Deny". It is working fine however I wonder if there is a way to take user input (comments) as mandatory when user clicks on "Deny" option in mail.

Comment: When you say embed a link to your task-item, I am not sure where the task-item would be. Are you talking about Flow approvals or maybe a PowerApps screen with options and a comments section?

Answer (score 0):

recommend you to use normal **"send e-mail"** option, so you can embed a link to your task-item there can an approver post a comment and take action **(Approve or Reject)**

then you'll be able to add/embed approvers comment on mail body